# Return Value if 4 columns match in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets that I am working with in Excel:

1) Master Price Sheet

2) Entry

My "Master Price Sheet" sheet includes specific lumber dimensions and specifications as well as an assigned pricing (There are probably 200 different options available for pricing purposes so it takes a long time to manually look up each price)

When I am entering lumber lists into my "Entry" sheet. . .I'd like to return the value from the column "Price" from the "Master Price Sheet" only if the values in columns "Size (W)", "Size (H)", "Length", and "Species" entered into the "Entry" sheet matches columns in the "Master Price Sheet" so that it can find the pricing for me

What formula would be able to help me out with this?

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated

**I've added images to this post below so that you can see what I'm working with**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to create a helper column in both tables, where you combine the four cells with an ampersand `&` sign. This will create a unique key that you can use in a lookup function like VLoookup or an Index/Match combination.

For example: in the Master table, insert a new column before the price and in that new column use the formula (starting in cell G3

```
=A3&C3&D3&E3
```

Do the same in the Entry sheet table. Then you can look up the price like this in cell H3 of the entry table:

```
=vlookup(G3,'Master Price Sheet'!F:G,2,False)
```

Copy down.

This is the basic principle. You can add more refinement by error catching, so you don't get errors if rows are empty. One of many approaches would be to wrap the formula in an IfError, or check that all four cells have content before performing the Vlookup.